# GridView don't set the margins in ToggleButton programmatically

Tags: android, gridview

I'm trying to set programmatically a ToggleButton inside of a Gridview. All seems that is working, but I can't set some properties like the margins between the togglebuttons that I'm adding in a loop for and this property:             toogleBtn.setAllCaps(false); don't work.

Thanks in advance

This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="@style/screen"
    android:id="@+id/ly_general"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/your_interest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_22"
        android:id="@+id/text_init_session"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_26"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_20"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/select_categories"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_init_session"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text_init_session"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/text_init_session"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewExplanation" />
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        style="@style/screen"
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewExplanation">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lyCategory"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_40">
       </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code in java class:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            final ToggleButton toogleBtn = new ToggleButton (RegisterThreeActivityNew.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);

        toogleBtn.setLayoutParams(params);
        toogleBtn.setWidth(140);
        toogleBtn.setHeight(20);
        toogleBtn.setTextSize(12);
        toogleBtn.setAllCaps(false);
        toogleBtn.setText(arrayList.get(i).getName());
        toogleBtn.setTextOff(arrayList.get(i).getName());
        toogleBtn.setTextOn(arrayList.get(i).getName());
        toogleBtn.setTextColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.white, null));
        toogleBtn.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_category, null));


        layoutCategories.addView(toogleBtn);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file inside toggle button set these properties

```
   android:minWidth="10dp"   // use what ever minimum value you need
   android:minHeight="10dp"
```

if you dont decrease the minwidth in xml then how much ever you try to decrease its width & height it won't work.I suffered with this problem for 2 days

Comment: Hi @Redman. I'm not adding the toogle button in the xml. I'm adding programmatically in the code. Take a look to my xml in my question

Comment: try keeping this  and see if working  `toogleBtn.setMinimumHeight(10)`  
`toogleBtn.setMinimumWidth(10)`